# How to do repentance for drinking alcohol?

Tags: sin, prayaschitta

What is the repentance for drinking spirituous liquor ? As drinking alcohol is considered as a sin.

Comment: For a person uninitiated in Gayatri mantra, there is no sin in alcohol consumption. For a brahmin, the punishment is burning of the tongue by consuming hot barley. Other ways include japa of gayatri, utilisation of tulasi leaves, observing Ekadashi & taking a dip in the Ganga.

Comment: @anubratabit, "For a person uninitiated in Gayatri mantra, there is no sin in alcohol consumption."--interested in knowing references to this. Thanks

Comment: Question needs more context. The solution might differ from sect to sect and prior initiation.